# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet, I get this error when i changed my model slightly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This was my model and everything was working fine:

```
public class events1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string report { get; set; }
    public string image1 { get; set; }
    public string image2 { get; set; }       
}
```

I just added this line in my model for a specific purpose and now when i add a new migration it says:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet

My new model is like this:

```
public class events1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string report { get; set; }
    public string image1 { get; set; }
    public string image2 { get; set; }

    //the new added line//

    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What you posted isn't related to the question. Where's the actual code that throws this error? What is the *actual* exception? Post the actual code and the full exception, including the call stack. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. The problem is very clear - you passed a `null` to a method that doesn't accept nulls. Which one? You don't show any calls in this code, so it's impossible to help. Try debugging your code for starters. The call stack will show *which* method threw and who called it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not map the property in to the database , You can mark it as Not Mapped.

```
[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
```

You can use the following using statement to get the attribute

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
```

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions, although I suspect you are right. You assume the migration looks at `ImageFile` and assumes it points to an entity, even though there's no such entity. Instead of ignoring this, or throwing and saying there's no such entity though, it just passes a `null` to the migarion code. *That* call throws a "silightly" unrelated exception

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `HttpPostedFileBase` is a complex type not supported by the data base.

So, try to ignore it

```
[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
```

OR

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<events1>().Ignore(t => t.ImageFile );
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Once I ignore it what will change regarding the architecture of the DB?